# Recommendation for writing data from SQLite file via Python sqlite3

Tags: python, database, multithreading, sqlite, multiprocessing

I have generated a giant SQLite database and need to get some data out of it. I wrote some script to do so, and profiling let to the unfortunate conclusion that the write process would take approx. 3 days with the current setup. I wrote the script as simplistic as possible to make it as fast as possible.

I am wondering if you have some trick to speed up the whole process. The database has an unique index, but the columns I am querying don't (because of duplicate rows for those).

Would it make sense to use any multi-processing Python library here?

The script would be like this:

```
import sqlite3

def write_from_query(db_name, table_name, condition, content_column, out_file):
    '''
    Writes contents from a SQLite database column to an output file

    Keyword arguments:
        db_name (str): Path of the .sqlite database file.
        table_name (str): Name of the target table in the SQLite file.
        condition (str): Condition for querying the SQLite database table.
        content_colum (str): Name of the column that contains the content for the output file.
        out_file (str): Path of the output file that will be written.

    '''
    # Connecting to the database file
    conn = sqlite3.connect('zinc12_drugnow_nrb(copy).sqlite')
    c = conn.cursor()

    # Querying the database and writing the output file
    c.execute('SELECT ({}) FROM {} WHERE {}'.format(content_column, table_name, condition))
    with open(out_file, 'w') as outf:
        for row in c:
            outf.write(row[0])

    # Closing the connection to the database
    conn.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    write_from_query(
        db_name='my_db.sqlite',
        table_name='my_table',
        condition='variable1=1 AND variable2<=5 AND variable3="Zinc_Plus"',
        content_column='variable4',
        out_file='sqlite_out.txt'
    )
```

[Link to this script on GitHub](https://github.com/rasbt/python_sqlite_code/blob/master/code/write_from_sqlite.py)

Thanks for your help, I am looking forward to your suggestions!

EDIT: 
more information about the database:

[image]
[image]

Comment: What is the size of the overall database and the size of the output file if you have done a complete run?

Comment: The size is about 50 Gb, and the expected output file is estimated to be ~ 15 Gb, currently, after a couple of hours (~4 hrs), I am at 1 Gb

Comment: please could you also provide the database schema, incase you do not know already, you can get this by logging into sqlite3 and entering .schema

Comment: I added some more information about the database structure to the initial question. Hope this is sufficient! Thanks!

Comment: This helps a little. Can you provide further information on the index, is this just on molecule_id? Also, it's not clear which table / columns your query is looking at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you are running the write_from_query functions for a huge amount of queries.

If so the problem is the missing indices on your filter criteria

This results in the following: for each query you execute, sqlite will loop through the whole 50GB of data and checks whether your conditions hold true. That is VERY inefficient.

The easiest way would be to slap indices on your columns

An alternative would be to formulate less queries that include multiple of your cases and then loop over that data again to split it it in different files. How well this can done however depends on how your data is structured.

I'm not sure about multiprocessing/threading, sqlite is not really made for concurrency, but I guess it could work out since you only read data...

Comment: Thanks, would a `.fetchmany()` make sense in this case? I guess a `fetchall()` is not feasible because of the limited RAM size?

Comment: How would I put indices on the columns? The problem is that they contain non-unique information, e.g., integers from 1-10

Comment: Indices do not require unique data. The unique constraint automatically creates an index, but you also can do that yourself. See "create index" syntax of sqlite. Best create one index mentioning all queried columns, ordered by how much they constrain the remaining possible matching rows.

Comment: Thanks, set up the code to let the indexing run over night and write out the results. Thanks a lot for all your help, it should be fine now :)

Comment: just a quick note: .fetchmany() or fetchall() don't work here, they are a little confusing since you will get the whole query result when you execute... you cannot "stream" it.

Answer (score 0):

Either you dump the content and filter in your own program - or you add indices to all columns you use in your conditions.

Adding indices to all the columns will take a long long time.
But for many different queries there is no alternative.

No multiprocessing will probably not help. An SSD might, or 64GiB Ram. But they are not needed with indices, queries will be fast on normal disks too.

In conclusion you created a Database without creating indices for the columns you want to query. With 8Mio rows this wont work.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I was thinking about the indices too, but I don't know how, since they contain non-unique information

Comment: See my comment on the other Answer.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst the process of actually writing this data to a file will take a while I would expect it to be more like minutes than days e.g. at a 50MB/s sequential write speed 15GB works out at around 5 mins.

I suspect that the issue is with the queries / lack of indexes. I would suggest trying to build composite indexes based on the combinations of columns that you need to filter on. As you will see from the documentation [here](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createindex.html), you can actually add as many columns as you want to an index.

Just to make you aware adding indexes will slow down inserts / updates to your database as every time it now needs to find the appropriate place in the relevant indexes to add data as well as appending data to the end of the tables, but this is probably your only option to speed up the queries.

Answer (score 0):

I will look at the unique indices! But meanwhile another thing I just stumbled upon... Sorry for writing an own answer for my question here, but I thought it is better for the organization...

I was thinking that the `.fetchall()` command could also speed up the whole process, but I find the sqlite3 documentation on this a little bit brief ... Would something like

```
with open(out_file, 'w') as outf:

    c.excecute ('SELECT * ...')
    results = c.fetchmany(10000)
    while results:
        for row in results:
            outf.write(row[0])
        results = c.fetchmany(10000)
```

make sense?